# How do I store registered trademark symbols(®) and em(—) dashes in a Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, special-characters, dbeaver

When importing a csv file that contains strings with special characters into a varchar column in a table in a Postgresql database, I notice that the registered trademark symbols (®) and em dashes (—) are both getting stored as �. The � is also what gets exported from the database.

How can I get the database to recognize/accept/store the ® and — symbols?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I imported the csv using the Import Data wizard in dBeaver. The data was imported "successfully" but the ® and — symbols got stored as � symbols. I expected the special characters to be accepted in a varchar column.

Comment: Nevermind. It was due an encoding issue. Saving the data-file as CSV UTF-8 instead of CSV in Excel fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing such characters is no problem, as long as the database encoding can encode these characters (`UTF8` is almost always the correct choice).

All you have to do is set `client_encoding` to the encoding of the CSV files when you import the data. DBeaver doesn't seem to allow you to select the encoding of the CSV file, so you should use a different tool. If you use `COPY` (or `psql`'s `\copy`), you can add the `ENCODING` option to specify the encoding of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html

Postgresql supports various character-sets, including UTF-8 which should cover all bases. The encoding of your database is unfortunately set during `initdb`  and the default is dependent on your system. The command would be:

```
initdb -E UTF8
```

The page documents no way to change it afterwards or on a per-table-basis, so you probably need to recreate the database and migrate your data (using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) for example).